# Python runs a function on all objects in a list

Tags: python

So i have this code here:

```
list = [[MyClass(), MyClass()], [MyClass()]]
list2 = [2, 2]

for i in range(len(list)):
    for j in range(len(list[i])):
        for k in range(list2[i]):
            list[i][j].list3.append(1)

for i in range(len(list)):
    for j in range(len(list[i])):
        print(list[i][j].list3)
```

with the Class:

```
class MyClass():
    list3 = []
```

and it outputs:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

instead of my expected:

```
[1, 1]
[1, 1]
[1, 1]
```

but i cant figure out whats wrong.

Comment: Count your `for` loops. Or you can work backwards and multiply the iterations. You will then see how many times you are appending to the lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MyClass():
    list3 = []
```

`list3` is a class variable, so all instances of the class share it.  Each time you append to `list3` on *any* instance, it's appending to that single shared list.

Fixing `MyClass` to make `list3` an instance variable will give you the behavior you want:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list3 = []
```

I'd also suggest simplifying your `for` loops, since they're a bit tough to follow; if you iterate by element it gets easier to figure out what each loop is doing.  (Also, avoid calling variables by builtin names like `list`!)

```
list1 = [[MyClass(), MyClass()], [MyClass()]]
list2 = [2, 2]

for sublist, num in zip(list1, list2):
    for obj in sublist:
        obj.list3.extend(1 for _ in range(num))

for sublist in list1:
    for obj in sublist:
        print(obj.list3)
```

prints:

```
[1, 1]
[1, 1]
[1, 1]
```